# Python 2.7 and 3.9, Windows 10, different structure in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\` && validation on env-var paths for Python 2.7

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

Community..
I notice in `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\` Python 2.7 has two folders.

- `Python27`
- `Scripts`

And Python 3.9 buries everything in a single folder of `Python39`.
Anyway to ratify it so Python 2.7 does the same ?

---

Also, my user and system environment-vars I think have an incorrect path for the Python 2.7 Scripts path.
The installation created (with me customising destination folder during wizard..) `C:\Program Files\Python27\Scripts` but the actual path for the `Scripts` folder is `C:\Program Files\Python27\Tools\Scripts` .. should I be changing it ?